# Input compilation error Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need `int num` to only accept numbers. If I input letters I get an error. Is there a way to immediately flag letters, or do I have to take `num` in as a *string* and run loops?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test 
{        
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input a number.");
        int num = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no variable declared (that is, declared as a `Scanner` which I  imagine is what you want, and instantiated) named `input`.

Comment: @Makoto Check the import statement. He might have not copied the whole code here

Comment: At that point then `input` would be a static variable, and would've likely been grabbed with the copy.  But you could be right...

Comment: Sorry about that. Yeah, I did have a variable declared as Scanner.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation of your code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [Scanner.hasNextInt():](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)

It Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the `nextInt()` method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
 System.out.println("Input a number.");
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
 while (!sc.hasNextInt()) sc.next();
 int num = sc.nextInt();

 System.out.println(num);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input an integer.");
        int num = 0;  // or any other default value
        try {
            num = input.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("You should've entered an integer like I told you. Fool.");
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If the user enters something that is not an integer, the code within the `catch` block will be executed.

Comment: Ok, so I tried this but now my num variable is not seen in the rest of my code. How do I fix that?

Comment: See the edit above. You can set `num` initially to whatever default value you want to have if the user gives you invalid input.

Comment: If the user inputs something invalid (not an integer), `num` will retain its default value of (in this case) 0.